# Mongoid embeds_many / embedded_in relations with Formtastic in ActiveAdmin...?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, activeadmin, formtastic, mongoid3

Whew - lots of projects wrapped up in this one and I've done some (extensive) searching to no avail, so throwing up a flare to see if anyone else is working with a similar stack and has a solution.

I'm using a [Mongoid-enabled fork of ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/Ostrzy/activeadmin-mongoid/tree/filter_support) to build an admin interface for a Rails 3 app.

ActiveAdmin (which builds its forms using Formtastic) seems to be playing along so far.  But I've run into a snag when trying to use this stack with Mongoid's `embeds_many` and `embedded_in` relations.  I'm trying to be a good citizen and use the proper data modeling technique with Mongo, but Formtastic doesn't seem to want to play along.

I'll share the specific error I'm getting, though it may be esoteric.

If I can't dig up a good solution, I'll suck it up and just use `has_many` and `belongs_to`, even though I know I'll be giving up the main benefit of MongoDB (the app won't be big enough to have the lack of joins / multiple queries be an issue, but I figured I'd do things the right way from the start!).

```
class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :events
  field :venue_name, type: String
end

class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :location
  field :event_name, type: String
end

ActiveAdmin.register Event do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :event_name
      f.input :location, :as => :select
    end
  f.buttons
end
```

It's choking on the `f.input :location` line and throwing:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `event_id' for #<Event:0x007fa4224a20e0>):
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
```

I changed the `:as => :select` to `:as => :check_boxes` and actually got it to display the correct Locations (though as checkboxes, not a select or radio).  But upon submitting the form, I'm then greeted with a:

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoParent (
  Problem:
  Cannot persist embedded document Event without a parent document.
)
```

In looking at the raw submission, it's trying to send my selection as "event_id" instead of the id of the parent document (Location).

Anyway - my gut is that I'm trying to fit a square peg into a round hole here, but if anyone else has any thoughts, they'd be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The error said it all. You cannot create an embedded record without the parent created first.

And yes, I think in your case has_many and belongs_to relation will be the right choice.